# How good is Webroot antivirus?

Tags: anti-virus

I need to renew my antivirus, and I have norton 360. But my friend got webroot and offered to give me the extra one that came in the package. Should I switch?

Answer (score 1):

Webroot rates well but the Norton product rates a bit better. At least in these tests[AV Test](http://www.av-test.org/certifications.php)